# Calculate certain # of business days from user entered date

Tags: forms, acrobat

I'm working on a PDF where the user enteres a date in field "startdate."
I need script to populate field "date1" with a new business date a specified number of days.

For example:

```
User types 9/7/2012 in "startdate" field :: I need "date1" field to say 9/11"
Note: this takes into account that 9/8 & 9/9 are weekend dates.
```

I've been able to generate this in Excel using WORKINGDAYS formula, but need to get it to work in Adobe Acrobat. 
I've got experience with form fields, but never been able to get them to calculate (aside from basic math).